# Using PHP to pass absolute file paths from config file to HTML

Tags: php, html, path, config, absolute

I just recently implemented a new directory schema that works as follows:

```
|| Directory Schema ||

>Shape_Search/  
    >public/                
        >css/       
        >img/
            >content/
            >layout/
        >js/
    >resources/             
        config.php      
        >Libraries/     
        >Classes/           
        >Templates/         
    >src/               
        >ImageUtilities/
        >RatingUtilities/
        >UserUtilities
    >README.txt
```

I need to be able to traverse the trajectories now that all the files aren't in one big folder. I've tried doing so by defining absolute path constants for all the major folders and placed them in a config.php file. I also stored absolute paths in a multi-dimensional array for some of the folders.

Whenever I try to use either of these stored paths to access files in my project I get nothing. Here is my configuration file and excerpts from my index.php file where I try using these methods.

```
/*
config.php
*/
$config = array(
    "dbCred" => array(
        "ai_search" => array(
            "hostname" => "localhost",
            "username" => "root",
            "password" => "",
            "dbname" => "ai_search"
        )
    ),
    "urls" => array(
        "baseUrl" => "http://localhost/Shape_Search/public"
    ),
    "paths" => array(
        "images" => array(
            "content" => $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/Shape_Search/public/img/content",
            "layout" => $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/Shape_Search/public/img/layout"
        )

    )
);
/*
Create constants for heavily used paths relative to config file location
*/
define("LIBRARY_PATH", realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '\Library');

define("CLASSES_PATH", realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "\Classes");

define("TEMPLATES_PATH", realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "\Templates");

define("IMAGE_UTIL_PATH", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/Shape_Search/src/ImageUtilities");

define("RATING_UTIL_PATH", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/Shape_Search/src/RatingUtilities");

define("USER_UTIL_PATH", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/Shape_Search/src/UserUtilities");
```

```
<p>
   <img src="<?php echo $config['paths']['images']['layout'];?> shapes-background.jpg" alt="VARIOUS SHAPES" width="500px">
</p>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo LIBRARY_PATH; ?>/fontawesome-free-5.15.4-web/css/all.css?v=51">
```

Comment: You can't use the servers absolute file paths for assets in HTML. In HTML, the document root is the root folder. So if you have: `/var/www/mysite.com/public` as root and set the `src` to an image as: `/var/www/mysite.com/public/img/foo.gif`, the server will try and load the file from: `/var/www/mysite.com/public/var/www/mysite.com/public/img/foo.gif`. You need to set it as: `/img/foo.gif`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Thank you.

|| config.php ||

```
    "paths" => array(
        "images" => array(
            "content" => realpath($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]) . "/Shape_Search/public/img/content",
            "layout" => realpath($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]) . "/Shape_Search/public/img/layout"
        )

    )
```

|| index.php ||

```
require_once ('../resources/config.php');
$backgroundImagePath = $config['paths']['images']['layout'] . '/shapes-background.jpg';
echo $backgroundImagePath;
```

```
<p>
    <img src="<?php echo $backgroundImagePath;?>" alt="VARIOUS SHAPES" width="500px">
</p>
```